# Bootstrap Column re-ordering / stacking in single Row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-float

I have 3 columns in a row for desktop versions

> brand-(length 3), search-(length 7) & cart-(length-2)

```
------------------------------------------------
|  Brand |           Search            |  Cart |
------------------------------------------------
```

When viewed in desktop mode the these three columns should appear as above, but when collapsed or seen in mobile browser the order should be as below and should look as same a below

> brand-(length 6), cart-(length-6) & search-(length 12)

```
------------------------------------------------
|           Brand      |         Cart          |
------------------------------------------------
|                   Search                     |
------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Column Reordering](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) (Push + Pull) to change the order when the viewport changes size. You have to place the two columns in the opposite order and apply `col-*push-*` / `col*-pull-*` to them so the stack order changes.

See working example Snippet at Full Page.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
      <div class="alert alert-info">Brand</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-push-6 col-sm-3 ">
      <div class="alert alert-danger">Cart</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-pull-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="alert alert-warning">Search</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```